# How to jump to a class definition in CodeRush

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, coderush

Just downloaded the CodeRush trial version and I can't easily find the one feature that I really wanted.  I would like to be able to start typing a class name and to jump to its definition, sort of like the quick navigator but I want it to search in closed files within my solution as well as open ones.  I know R# has that ability, I assume CodeRush does too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Q</kbd> (this will bring up the Quick Nav)

2) Start typing the name of the Type, Variable, etc.

3) Hit Enter to select when the target shows in the top of the list

If the scope is not already set to "Solution" (you can tell via the drop-down on the right of the Quick Nav), you can hit <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd> to set and it will save the state.

Comment: I am still not able to locate the File in the Solution Structure in Visual Studio. The file is just opened, but not highlighted in the solution tree.

Answer (score 1):

A quick remark to the excellent answer by Troy, if the version you downloaded is the newer one, 3.2, the Quick Nav has been remapped to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Q</kbd>.